# AviReader - getNext

Tags: c#, avi

I'm using SharpAvi's AviWriter to create AVI files.  I can get any standard video player to play these AVI files.  20 frames per second with no compression. [using example from this link](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0xae333d1a2463f82125b203dc52f62380ab086214ec45212aa65aa65154aeede7&fullName=FilmScanner/Video.cs&project=JollySwagman/Super8)
so that seems to be working fine.

failing to find SharpAVi's AviReader anywhere I've resorted to using AForge.Video.VFW's AVIReader but it can only show me a black screen for each frame before index 128 and then if fails to get next frame.
the example I'm using is straighforward

```
// instantiate AVI reader
AVIReader reader = new AVIReader( );
// open video file
reader.Open( "test.avi" );
// read the video file
while ( reader.Position - reader.Start < reader.Length )
{
    // get next frame
    Bitmap image = reader.GetNextFrame( );
    // .. process the frame somehow or display it
}
```

I have my app's Build set to x86 to accommodate both these AVI apps 32 bit settings.
and using AForge.Video.VFW AVIWriter fails to write files with more than some 500 +/- frames.(video player needs to rebuild index and C#IDE "fails opening AVI file".

does SharpAVI have an AVIReader?  because I haven't found one.